# Spring security occasionally requires retype passwords three times to login

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring 3.0.5 security feature to directly perform user authentication. I am using basic authentication. Every morning when I try to login for the first time, it requires me to enter the correct passwords exact three times in order to login. I am sure the correct passwords were entered. The problem does not happen afterwards, even when I try to login from a different account.

For more information, my application server uses port 8443 and I set port redirect from 443 to 8443 using iptables on the Linux host. Not sure if this has any impact

I am using database as the backend for authentication. And there is only one DB with no clustering.

The following is my configuation file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">


<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<http pattern="/loggedout.jsp" security="none"/>

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/page/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <http-basic/>
    <remember-me />
</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha"/>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Does anyone encounter the same problem before or have some idea on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of authentication backend are you using? (e.g. database, in memory, CAS, etc.)

Comment: Hi Willie Wheeler, I am using database as the backend.

Comment: OK. I haven't encountered this before but you will probably need to provide a lot more background information to get any kind of good answer. It could be any number of things. It could be network related, it could be that you're load balancing across databases and they have inconsistent data, etc. Is it always exactly three, or is it sometimes two? Is it always specific accounts or does it happen to certain accounts? Etc. Provide as much information as might be relevant and that will help people brainstorm. Posting your configuration file(s) probably wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Hi Willie, thanks for the suggestions. I edited my question accordingly. In particular, it is always exact three time, not two not four. It happens every morning when I try to login for the first time. There is no DB clustering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "it happens every morning when I try to login for the first time" part of your comment is highly relevant. I'll bet you are dealing with a stale connection in the connection pool.

There is a way to configure connection pools to use a test query to see whether the connection is any good before trying to use it. For example if you are using DBCP I believe the property is called `validationQuery`. I don't know all the ins and outs of what is going on with your particular pool and configuration, but I've seen this (this = early morning behavior that fixes itself) before and it happens with stale connections.

Good luck. :-)